# Module not found: Error: in Vue and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Im following a YT video installing a Vue and Laravel.

So far the resources forlder looks like:

```
- resources
   - js
       - app.js
       - vue
            -app.vue
```

On the `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './vue/app'

const app = new Vue({
    el : "#app",
    components : { App }
});
```

On the `app.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello World
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        
    }
</script>
```

And if I do `npm run hot`

Im getting an error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/app' in
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test-app\resources\js'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `import App from './vue/app.vue'` Just specified the .vuew extension and try

Answer (score 0):

Rename your app.vue to App.vue